# Matrix multiplication gives unsual result in Python (SciPy/PyLab)

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

I'm new to Python, and a bit rusty with my linear algebra, so perhaps this is a simple question. I'm trying to implement a Taylor Series expansion on a Matrix to compute exp(A), where A is just a simple 3x3 matrix. The formula, BTW for this expansion is sum( A^n / n! ).

My routine works alright up to n=9, but at n=10, the numbers in the Matrix suddenly become negative. This is the problem.

> > > A**9
> > >       matrix([[ 250130371,  506767656,  688136342],
> > >               [ 159014912,  322268681,  437167840],
> > >               [ 382552652,  775012944, 1052574077]])
> > >
> > > A**10
> > >       matrix([[-1655028929,  1053671123, -1327424345],
> > >               [ 1677887954,  -895075635,   319718665],
> > >               [ -257240602,  -409489685, -1776533068]])

Intuitively A^9 * A should produce larger numbers for each member of the matrix, but as you can see, A^10 isn't giving that result.

Any ideas?

```
from scipy import *
from numpy import *
from numpy.linalg import *
#the matrix I will use to implement exp(A)
A = mat('[1 3 5; 2 5 1; 2 3 8]')
#identity matrix
I = mat('[1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1]')
#first step in Taylor Expansion (n=0)
B = I
#second step in Taylor Expansion (n=1)
B += A
#start the while loop in the 2nd step
n = 2
x=0
while x<10:
    C = (A**n)/factorial(n)
    print C
    print " "
    n+=1
    B+= C
    print B
    x+=1

print B
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Big numbers becoming negative sounds like an integer overflow. Have you tried setting up a matrix with a larger integer type?

Comment: You should avoid the `from module import *` type imports. You just polluted your namespace with a ton of functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your matrix is created with elements of type `int32` (32-bit integer). You can see this by printing the value of `A.dtype`. 32-bit integers can only hold values up to about 2 billion, so after that they will wrap around to negative values.

If 64-bit integers are large enough, you can use them instead:

```
A = mat('[1 3 5; 2 5 1; 2 3 8]', dtype=numpy.int64)
```

Otherwise, you can use floating point numbers. They have a much larger maximum value, but limited precision, so there may be some inaccuracies.

```
A = mat('[1 3 5; 2 5 1; 2 3 8]', dtype=float)
```

In this case floating-point is probably the best choice, since you don't want your results to be integers after dividing by `n!`.

Comment: Also, considering the calculations he's doing, using integers doesn't make much sense in the first place. I would guess that he's introducing far more inaccuracies by using integer (truncating) division in `C = (A**n)/factorial(n)`.

Comment: @Joe: Thanks, I added this to my answer. I don't think integer division was a problem here though because `scipy.factorial` returns floating-point values unless you pass the `exact=True` argument.

Comment: Thank you, sir! I had a feeling that was the problem, but digging through the scipy documentation I couldn't find the syntax for implementing a matrix with float values.

Comment: Ah, you're right... I just assumed that it would return an int.

Comment: @Taj - That's because it's not a part of scipy, it's numpy.  Have a look at the basic numpy tutorial: http://www.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial and the user's guide: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/index.html#user and the numpy docs: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/index.html#reference

Answer (score 3):

I don't know much about scientific python but I do know what is going wrong. It seems that the matrix elements are represented as 32 bit signed integers. That means that they are restricted to the range -2^31 <= x < 2^31. At A^10, the numbers become too big and they "wrap around". I checked and the top-left coefficient actually is 2639938267, which, when wrapped around, gives 2639938267 - 2^32 = -1655028929.

I don't know how to set the data type in python, so I don't know how you can solve this. I'm sure it's possible, though.

(I could also suggest you try sage: www.sagemath.org, which is mathematics software based on python. It automatically uses infinite precision. It's how I checked these numbers just now).

Good luck! Timo